# How do can I remove text from a string in Ruby when there are multiple instances of the text in the string

Tags: ruby, string

An example of the string:

```
"6 red cables, 4 white cables, 9 blue cables"
```

I want to remove "cables" so that it reads

```
"6 red, 4 white, 9 blue"
```

I looked at the `slice` and `sub` methods, but they only remove the first instance of "cables". Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Consider regex? gsub?

Comment: call gsub("cables", "") on your string. or, more general, make a function like `def my_fun(s, x); s.gsub(x, ''); end`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `String#gsub`:

```
2.2.0 :003 > "6 red cables, 4 white cables, 9 blue cables".gsub(" cables", "")
 => "6 red, 4 white, 9 blue"
```

Answer (score -1):

Reference (compares sub vs gsub):
http://www.dotnetperls.com/sub-ruby

**Answer**

```
cleand_value = "6 red cables, 4 white cables, 9 blue cables".gsub("cables", '') 
 Output "6 red , 4 white , 9 blue "
```

**Explanation:**

```
value = "abc abc"
# Gsub replaces all instances.
value = value.gsub("abc", "---")
puts value

Output

--- ---
```

You then can get rid of all the white spaces after the commas the same way.

```
cleaner_value = cleaned_value.gsub(", ", ",") #replaces all instances
output "6 red, 4 white, 9 blue"
```

Or use the other solutions and do

```
cleand_value = "6 red cables, 4 white cables, 9 blue cables".gsub(" cables", '') #notice the space before cables. May cause problems unless you know exactly the input
```

Comment: This returns `"6 red , 4 white , 9 blue "`. To remove those spaces you need to change `"cables"` to `" cables"`, but then you have @Igor's earlier solution.

Comment: Please don't toss out code only. Explain why it's useful and what it does. Handing out code by itself is like throwing someone a fish. Explaining is like teaching them how to fish. The later is better because they'll understand what to do next time.

Comment: @theTinMan I edited response. Thanks for the advice, and I like the analogy...seems familiar :D